# Evaluate $\int xe^{-0.5x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried to evaluate this term:

$$\int xe^{-0.5x^2}dx$$

but I couldn't find any way other than Wolfram Alpha.

How can I find the solution by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we get $$-e^{-x^2/2}+C$$ it is easy to be seen

Comment: and is there a way to solve it for someone who does not just see it?

Comment: substitute $$t=-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the derivative of $e^{-0.5x^2}$?

Comment: It seems to be $-xe^{-0.5x^2}$ is this right?

Comment: @oneguy correct. Note that this is almost what you've got inside the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Put $-0.5x^2 = t$

On differentiate,

$-0.5 \times 2x^{2-1} dx = dt$

$-xdx = dt$

$xdx = -dt$

Then we have,

$- \int e^t dt$

On integration,

$-e^t + c$

Put value of t,

$-e^{-0.5x^2} + c$

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule by setting $u \mapsto \sqrt{u} =: x$,
we have
$$
\int x e^{-x^{2}/2} = \int \sqrt{u}e^{-u/2}\cdot D\sqrt{u} = \int \sqrt{u}e^{-u/2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} = \frac{1}{2}\int e^{-u/2} = -\int D e^{-u/2} = -e^{-u/2} + \text{constant} = -e^{-x^{2}/2} + \text{constant}.
$$